# Importing files when using PHP configuration files in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony6

I have a Symfony's services.yaml which defines a "basic" container configuration and import di.php files to configure some specific services.

```
imports:
  - { resource: '../src/**/di.php' }

services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true

App\:
  resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
      - '../src/**/di.php'
      - '../src/**/Entity/'
      - '../src/**/Model/'
      - '../src/Authorization/AuthorizationProcessor/'
      - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

For instance, here, I explicitly exclude `src/Authorization/Processor` folder because it has a `di.php` file that holds service definitions for this specific namespace.

This approach works.

But when I replace the services.yaml with `services.php`

```
<?php
return static function (ContainerConfigurator $di): void {
    $di->import('../src/**/di.php');

    $services = $di->services()
                   ->defaults()
                   ->autowire()
                   ->autoconfigure();

    $services->load('App\\', '../src/')
             ->exclude([
                 '../src/**/di.php',
                 '../src/**/Entity/',
                 '../src/**/Model/',
                 '../src/Authorization/AuthorizationProcessor/',
                 '../src/Kernel.php',
             ]);
```

To me, it looks the same but with `services.php` I get an error

> The file "../src" does not exist (in:
> "/var/www/app/src/Authorization/AuthorizationProcessor") in
> /var/www/app/config/services.php (which is being imported from
> "/var/www/app/src/Kernel.php").

Comment: I notice that the "exclude" arrays are different in your YAML and PHP configuration files.

Comment: It just a typo. They are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. It has nothing to do with path. What is important - the order.

When it is YAML than you could have first `imports`, then `services` section. But when it is PHP - the `import` has to be the last instruction.

As soon as I've moved the `import` after the `$services->load` it starts working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try replacing all the paths with this format:

```
$di->import(__DIR__.'/../src/**/di.php');
```

Note the added `/` in the beginning of the string.